# Reactjs Object State Change Events in Form

Tags: reactjs

So I've got a basic form that I'm rendering and the component needs state.  I would prefer for the state to be an object instead of a list of values so I can easily call JSON.stringify(stateObject).  This would enable me to easily refactor into a more re-usable HOC later where I pass the state object definition & urls as a configuration.

Anyways, what happens is that every time I modify an input, it clears out the properties which were not changed and sets the property which was changed.

See initial entry below

[image: Initial Entry]

I add input to a different input and it removes the first input and adds the second input.  Notice that Facility Name is now cleared and address is now populated.

[image]

Below is the code which is doing this

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Row, Col, Button, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

function FacilitiesCreate() {
  const [Name, setName] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [Latitude, setLatitude] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [Longitude, setLongitude] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [Description, setDescription] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [AddressLineOne, setAddressLineOne] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [AddressLineTwo, setAddressLineTwo] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [City, setCity] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [State, setState] = useState("");//not ideal
  const [ZipCode, setZipCode] = useState(""); //not ideal
  const [Facility, setFacility] = useState({
    Name: "",
    Latitude: 0,
    Longitude: 0,
    Description: "",
    AddressLineOne: "",
    AddressLineTwo: "",
    City: "",
    State: "",
    ZipCode: "",
  }); //I want to be able to JSON.stringify this for my body post call :D see handleSubmit
  
    const createFacilityEndpoint = "https://localhost:7113/api/facilities";
    
      const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          let response = await fetch(createFacilityEndpoint, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(Facility),
          });
          if (response.ok) {
            alert("YAY!");
          }
      };
  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>Create New Facility</h2>
      <p>facility name: {Facility.Name}</p>
      <br></br>
      <p>address: {Facility.AddressLineOne}</p>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Location Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Location's Name"
              onChange={(e) => setFacility({ Name: e.target.value })}
            />
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Latitude</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="float"
              placeholder="Enter Latitude"
              onChange={(e) => setLatitude(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Longitude</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="float"
              placeholder="Enter Longitude"
              onChange={(e) => setLongitude(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="textarea"
              rows={3}
              placeholder="Enter Description"
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder="1234 Main St"
            onChange={(e) => setFacility({ AddressLineOne: e.target.value })}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
          <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor"
            onChange={(e) => setAddressLineTwo(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
            <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="Miami Beach"
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
            <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="FL"
              onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
            <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="33141"
              onChange={(e) => setZipCode(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Row>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default FacilitiesCreate;
```

So the above is kinda cool, except it keeps nuking the other properties in the Facility State object...

Comment: You're calling `setFacility` with an object with a single value in it; perhaps you're confusing it with old `setState`.

Comment: @DaveNewton probably.  I just started learning reactJS this week and the docs are all over the place between new and old paradigms.

Comment: The `setState` v state hook difference is discussed in the `useState` hook docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
(e) => setFacility({ Name: e.target.value })
```

to:

```
(e) => setFacility((oldValue) => ({ ...oldValue, Name: e.target.value }))
```

There is an option with `useState` to provide a callback function to the `set` function. This callback gets the old value of the state as parameter, so you can use it for the new state you want to set.

Comment: it does not like this syntax at all:
onChange={(e) => setFacility((oldValue) => { ...oldValue, Name: e.target.value })}

Comment: I updated the solution, I forgot to add `()` around the newly created object

Comment: Baller.  Does exactly what it needs to.  That's some pretty sophisticated syntax.

Comment: You might want to move it to a separate `const` for better readability ;)

Comment: wouldn't I end up with like 10 const?  I suppose, i've got 10 different things now, be super baller if it could be consolidated into a single const definition.

Comment: actually if I can consolidate this into a single const definition handler, then I'm in great shape for refactoring this into a very simple re-usable component.

Comment: If you'd add a data-attribute to the control, you could use that from the event you get back as well. It woud result into 1 function that would work on all `Control` components.
A different option would be to extract the `Control` to a separate component in which you also get the name as prop. That way you could implement a different `onChange` that returns for instance `{ key: 'Name',  value: 'Some name' }`

Comment: I've asked a seperate question on this subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819315/reactjs-consolidate-form-onclick-handlers