# ReactJS | Consolidate Form onChange Handlers

Tags: reactjs

So check out this one for more details on original problem: [Reactjs Object State Change Events in Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72818276/reactjs-object-state-change-events-in-form#72818372)

Now I'd really like to consolidate my handlers, I've ended up with a bunch of inline onChange handlers, which if I want to extract and re-use my code is not really acheivable unless I can consolidate them into a single handler.  How would one go about consolidating these into a single function which can handle everything?

```js
  <Container>
      <h2>Create New Facility</h2>
      <p>facility name: {Facility.Name}</p>
      <br></br>
      <p>address: {Facility.AddressLineOne}</p>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Location Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              placeholder="Location's Name"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  Name: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Latitude</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="float"
              placeholder="Enter Latitude"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  Latitude: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Longitude</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="float"
              placeholder="Enter Longitude"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  Longitude: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              as="textarea"
              rows={3}
              placeholder="Enter Description"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  Description: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder="1234 Main St"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                ...oldValue,
                AddressLineOne: e.target.value,
              }))
            }
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
          <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                ...oldValue,
                AddressLineTwo: e.target.value,
              }))
            }
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
            <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="Miami Beach"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  City: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
            <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="FL"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  State: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
            <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              placeholder="33141"
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFacility((oldValue) => ({
                  ...oldValue,
                  ZipCode: e.target.value,
                }))
              }
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Row>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Container>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a package for this? I think something like Formik (https://formik.org) could really help you out and make it really easy to use/understand

Comment: Reviewing it now.  I had not seen it.  I'm modernizing my web ui dev skills after having spent a long time working on embedded systems and backend data.

Comment: Sweet, I was basically just building formik.  Formik much better, exactly what I was trying to do "Cut down on the annoying".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can implement the hook that manages the form state and allows you to register new fields:

```js
function useForm({ defaultValues = {} }) {
  const [ values, setValues ] = useState(defaultValues);

  const field = (name) => {
    const onChange = (e) => { 
      setValues((current) => ({ ...current, [name]: e.target.value })); 
    };

    const value = values[name];

    return { name, onChange, value };
  };

  return { field, values };
}
```

Then apply it to the form

```js
function FacilityForm() {
  const { values, field } = useForm({});

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Label>Location Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        {...field('location')}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Location's Name"
      />

      <Form.Label>Latitude</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        {...field('latitude')}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Latitude"
      />
   </Form>
  );
}
```

This is a very simple implementation that may lack the features you might want to have (e.g validation, nested keys, etc.). I would recommend you consider the existing libraries for that. For example, [react-hook-forms](https://react-hook-form.com/) is very good for such purposes